# BadRequestError while uploading data using bulk loader

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

Hello I have created sample Greeting application in Google app engine.

Now I am trying to upload data using bulk loader.

But its giving BadRequestError.This is the code for that:

```
D:\Study\M.Tech\Summer\Research\My Work\Query Transformation\Experiment\Tools\Bu
lkloader\bulkloader test>appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --url=http://bulkex.
appspot.com/remote_api --application=bulkex --filename=config.yml

Creating bulkloader configuration.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20111008.175810
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20111008.175810.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20111008.175810.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to bulkex.appspot.com/remote_api
Please enter login credentials for bulkex.appspot.com
Email: shyam.rk22@gmail.com
Password for shyam.rk22@gmail.com:
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['__Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__']
[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-3] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\adaptive
_thread_pool.py", line 176, in WorkOnItems
status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)

File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools \bulkloader.py",line 764, in PerformWork transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 1170, in _TransferItem
    self, retry_parallel=self.first)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 1471, in GetEntities
    results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 1442, in _QueryForPbs
    raise datastore._ToDatastoreError(e)
BadRequestError: app s~bulkex cannot access app bulkex's data
[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-3: app s~bulkex cannot access app bulkex's data


[INFO    ] Have 0 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 0 entities (6466 bytes) transferred in 25.6 seconds
```

Answer (score 5):

Note the warning under `--application` in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html and use `--url` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did not get it from this link...

Can you explore it...?

This is what you should know about my application:

1. I have made this application in JAVA and not PYTHON...

2. For remote_api, i have made entry in web.xml...do we need to do any other settings for that...?

Comment: Drop the `--application` argument from the command line you're using above.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I removed the --application=APPID parameter from the statement and the code executed and built out the config.yml file with all my Kinds from the Datastore!